# Alamofire completion handler to retry on session timeout

Tags: swift, authentication, alamofire

We are interacting with a legacy API which times out users after one hour.  How can you write an Alamofire completion handler which handles a session timeout response by then issuing a Login request to reestablish the session and then retrying the original request?

Comment: What about this https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#requestretrier ?

Comment: Thanks let me see if I can get that to work

Comment: Trying...  having an issue with this.  Posted a separate question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40011061/alamofire-requestretrier-trigger